# What's the issue with my avocado plant?

Tags: diagnosis, avocado

This leaf fell off the plant few days ago..
[image: Lead]

But I've been noticing this leaf one side dried for almost a month before that, is anything wrong with my plant, is it trying to tell me something?

I water about 20oz alternate days, fertilized it with organic fruit fertilizer.

This is the whole plant, the nursery told its about 1.5 years old, grafted (i could notice the cut in the bottom). About 5.5ft tall
[image: Plant]

Trunk of the plant
[image: Trunk and base]

Leaf near base of the trunk
[image: Leaf near base of the trunk]

Leaf near top of the trunk
[image: Leaf near top of the trunk]

Comment: No problem if this is happening to older leaves...but need to see closeups of other leaves.  This will help tell you what chemicals it needs to be healthier...such as if I had to guess just by this leaf this guy needs more nitrogen, pH of the soil checked, possibly iron and possibly to many salts ie) tap water.  The picture of the plant is telling my that FIRST get that dang label off and send a picture of the soil and base of your plant.  Your plant looks rather healthy!  Only water when the soil dries out a bit, not every other day.  Careful with fertilizer...

Comment: Anand...very healthy!  I'd pull that soil away from the base until you see the roots.  Otherwise, from what I am seeing you've no problems.  Pinch the apical buds (the buds at the very tips of branches) and you'll get more growth from the sides.

Comment: I don't see any problems